# How to get rid of unwanted text in sql database?

Tags: mysql, parsing, content-management-system

i have to move articles from one website to another.
The articles in the old database contain some kind of code i don't recognize and i don't even know what CMS has been used previously since the creator of the old site is dead or something.

Here's an excerpt from the database:

```
a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:4:"TEXT";s:8:"elements";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:3:"RTE";s:7:"content";s:486:"%3Cp%3EDas%20r%26ouml%3Bmische%20Gemeinwesen%20war%20beim%20Tod%20des%20Augustus%20keine%20erbliche%20Monarchie.%20Die%20Herrschaft%20%26uuml%3Bber%20die%20R%26ouml%3Bmer%20ging%20nach%20seinem%20Tod%20nicht%20automatisch%20auf%20den%20n%26auml%3Bchsten%20m%26auml%3Bnnlichen%20Anverwandten%20%26uuml%3Bber.%20Im%20Gegenteil%2C%20komplizierte%2C%20rechtliche%20Schritte%20waren%20die%20Voraussetzung%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20der%20Thronwechsel%20problemlos%20von%20statten%20ging.%3C%2Fp%3E";}}}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGES";s:8:"elements";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGE1";s:7:"content";s:16:"570_a201ebec.jpg";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGE2";s:7:"content";s:0:"";}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:5:"CLASS";s:7:"content";s:12:"freigestellt";}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"LEGEND";s:7:"content";s:33:"Augustusstatue%20von%20Primaporta";}}}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:4:"TEXT";s:8:"elements";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:3:"RTE";s:7:"content";s:3544:"%3Cp%3EWas%20bedeutete%20das%20damals%20%26uuml%3Bberhaupt%2C%20Herrschaft%20%26uuml%3Bber%20die%20R%26ouml%3Bmer%3F%20Augustus%20behauptete%20ja%20von%20sich%20selbst%2C%20er%20habe%20lediglich%20an%20Autorit%26auml%3Bt%20die%20anderen%20R%26ouml%3Bmer%20%26uuml%3Bberragt.%20Doch%20die%20Wahrheit%20sah%20anders%20aus.%20Er%20verf%26uuml%3Bgte%20vor%20allem%20%26uuml%3Bber%20zwei%20Privilegien%2C%20die%20ihn%20zu%20einem%20unumschr%26auml%3Bnkten%20Herrscher%20machten.%20F%26uuml%3Br%20seine%20milit%26auml%3Brische%20Herrschaft%20war%20das%20%3Cem%3EImperium%20Proconsulare%3C%2Fem%3E%20am%20wichtigsten.%20W%26auml%3Bhrend%20ein%20einfacher%20senatorischer%20Prokonsul%20lediglich%20in%20einer%20Provinz%20sein%20Amt%20aus%26uuml%3Bbte%20und%20in%20dieser%20seiner%20Provinz%20tats%26auml%3Bchlich%20die%20gleichen%20Vollmachten%20besa%26szlig%3B%20wie%20Augustus%2C%20verf%26uuml%3Bgte%20der%20Kaiser%20%26uuml%3Bber%20eine%20ganze%20Reihe%20von%20Provinzen.%20Die%20waren%20zudem%20so%20ausgew%26auml%3Bhlt%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20alle%20wichtigen%20Heeresteile%20in%20ihnen%20stationiert%20waren.%20Damit%20war%20er%20nat%26uuml%3Brlich%20jedem%20anderen%20r%26ouml%3Bmischen%20Beamten%20milit%26auml%3Brisch%20weit%20%26uuml%3Bberlegen%20und%20konnte%20mit%20Waffengewalt%20jeden%20Widerstand%20brechen.%20Die%20Herrschaft%20des%20Augustus%20und%20seiner%20Nachfolger%20war%20-%20auch%20wenn%20sie%20es%20noch%20so%20gut%20zu%20verschleiern%20wu%26szlig%3Bten%20-%20nichts%20anderes%20als%20eine%20Milit%26auml%3Brdiktatur.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3EUm%20die%20Senatoren%20aber%20in%20dem%20Glauben%20zu%20wiegen%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20alles%20seinen%20gewohnten%20demokratischen%20Gang%20ginge%2C%20lie%26szlig%3B%20sich%20Augustus%20eine%20zweite%20Macht%20verleihen%2C%20die%20Tribunicia%20Potestas.%20Sie%20r%26auml%3Bumte%20ihm%20die%20gleichen%20Privilegien%20ein%2C%20wie%20sie%20fr%26uuml%3Bher%20die%20Volkstribunen%20besessen%20hatten.%20So%20konnte%20der%20Kaiser%20ganz%20legal%20jeden%20Gesetzesvorschlag%20einbringen%20und%20gegen%20jeden%20Beschlu%26szlig%3B%20eines%20Beamten%20das%20Veto%20(%22ich%20verbiete%22)%20einlegen.%20Im%20wesentlichen%20st%26uuml%3Btzte%20sich%20das%20Kaisertum%20w%26auml%3Bhrend%20des%20gesamten%20ersten%20Jahrhunderts%20n.%20Chr.%20auf%20diese%20beiden%20Privilegien.%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3EDoch%20ein%20Sch%26ouml%3Bnheitsfehler%20blieb.%20Beide%20Vollmachten%20waren%20nicht%20erblich%2C%20sondern%20wurden%20vom%20Senat%20verliehen.%20Wollte%20nun%20Augustus%2C%20oder%20irgendein%20anderer%20Kaiser%20nach%20ihm%2C%20auf%20die%20Wahl%20seines%20Nachfolgers%20Einflu%26szlig%3B%20nehmen%2C%20so%20mu%26szlig%3Bte%20er%20durchsetzen%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20dieser%20Nachfolger%20noch%20zu%20seinen%20Lebzeiten%20das%20Imperium%20Proconsulare%20und%20die%20Tribunicia%20Potestas%20verliehen%20bekam.%20So%20gab%20es%20also%20-%20bei%20einer%20ordentlich%20geregelten%20Nachfolge%20-%20stets%20zwei%20%22Kaiser%22.%20Starb%20einer%20von%20ihnen%2C%20so%20lief%20alles%20weiter%20wie%20bisher%2C%20nur%20mu%26szlig%3Bte%20sich%20der%20%26Uuml%3Bberlebende%20wieder%20um%20einen%20neuen%20Mitregenten%20umsehen.%20Augustus%20hatte%20das%20mehrmals%20in%20seiner%20Amtszeit%20getan.%20Agrippa%20-%20Ehemann%20von%20Iulia%2C%20der%20Tochter%20des%20Augustus%2C%20und%20Vater%20der%20potentiellen%20Nachfolger%2C%20Caius%20und%20Lucius%20Caesar%20%26ndash%3B%20war%20sein%20Mitregent%20gewesen.%20Er%20wurde%20von%20Tiberius%20-%20dem%20Stiefsohn%20des%20Augustus%20-%20abgel%26ouml%3Bst.%3C%2Fp%3E";}}}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGES";s:8:"elements";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGE1";s:7:"content";s:16:"571_0633fda9.jpg";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGE2";s:7:"content";s:16:"572_05111ca7.jpg";}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:5:"CLASS";s:7:"content";s:12:"freigestellt";}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"LEGEND";s:7:"content";s:335:"TIBERIUS%2C%2014-37%20AD.%20As%20im%20Namen%20des%20Drusus%20des%20J%C3%83%C2%BCngeren%2C%2022-23.%20PIETAS%20Verschleierte%20weibliche%20B%C3%83%C2%BCste%20mit%20Diadem%20n.%20r.%20Rv.%20DRVSVS%20CAESAR%20TI%20AVGVSTI%20F%20TR%20POT%20ITER%20um%20SC%2015%2C12%20g.%20BN%2048%2C%2074.%20BMC%20133%2C%2098.%20RIC%2097%2C%2043.%20C.%201.";}}}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:4:"TEXT";s:8:"elements";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:3:"RTE";s:7:"content";s:4164:"%3Cp%3EAuch%20Tiberius%20sorgte%20sich%20nach%20seiner%20Macht%26uuml%3Bbernahme%20um%20die%20Nachfolge.%20Er%20besa%26szlig%3B%20einen%20leiblichen%20Sohn%2C%20Drusus%2C%20und%20hatte%20auf%20Befehl%20des%20Augustus%20seinen%20Neffen%20Germanicus%20adoptiert.%20Damit%20verf%26uuml%3Bgte%20Tiberius%20%26uuml%3Bber%20zwei%20potentielle%20Mitherrscher.%20Wer%20nun%20die%20Macht%20mit%20ihm%20teilen%20sollte%2C%20dies%20lie%26szlig%3B%20Tiberius%20erst%20einmal%20offen.%20Er%20gab%20beiden%20jungen%20M%26auml%3Bnnern%20die%20Chance%2C%20sich%20in%20politischen%20und%20milit%26auml%3Brischen%20Aktionen%20zu%20bew%26auml%3Bhren.%20Erst%20als%20Germanicus%20im%20Jahre%2019%20n.%20Chr.%20starb%2C%20entschlo%26szlig%3B%20sich%20Tiberius%2C%20Drusus%20zum%20n%26auml%3Bchsten%20Kaiser%20zu%20machen%2C%20und%20veranla%26szlig%3Bte%20den%20Senat%2C%20seinem%20Sohn%20im%20Fr%26uuml%3Bhjahr%20des%20Jahres%2023%20die%20%3Cem%3ETribunicia%20Potestas%3C%2Fem%3E%20zu%20verleihen.%20Anl%26auml%3B%26szlig%3Blich%20dieses%20Ereignisses%20wurde%20unsere%20M%26uuml%3Bnze%20gepr%26auml%3Bgt.%20Wir%20lesen%20in%20der%20Umschrift%20DRVSVS%20CAESAR%20TI%20AVGVSTI%20F%20TR%20POT%20ITER%20Drusus%20Caesar%2C%20Sohn%20des%20Tiberius%20Augustus%2C%20der%20f%26uuml%3Br%20mehrere%20Jahre%20die%20Macht%20eines%20Tribunen%20inne%20hat.%20Damit%20h%26auml%3Btte%20nun%20eigentlich%20alles%20so%20sch%26ouml%3Bn%20geregelt%20ablaufen%20k%26ouml%3Bnnen.%20Doch%20Tacitus%20berichtet%20uns%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20Drusus%20einen%20Neider%20hatte%2C%20den%20Stadtpr%26auml%3Bfekten%20Seianus.%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3EWenn%20wir%20den%20packenden%20Bericht%20des%20Tacitus%20lesen%2C%20m%26uuml%3Bssen%20wir%20uns%20vor%20Augen%20halten%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20sein%20Autor%20stolz%20darauf%20war%2C%20im%20Senat%20zu%20sitzen%2C%20und%20auf%20einen%20Ritter%20wie%20Seianus%20nur%20ver%26auml%3Bchtlich%20herabblicken%20konnte.%20So%20unterstellte%20er%20Seianus%20alles%20Schlechte.%20Er%20behauptete%2C%20einzig%20sein%20Ehrgeiz%20sei%20der%20Grund%20gewesen%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20Seianus%20sich%20an%20die%20Ehefrau%20des%20Drusus%20heranmachte%2C%20die%20der%20leichtlebige%20Kaisersohn%20viel%20zu%20oft%20allein%20lie%26szlig%3B.%20Nur%20um%20Livilla%20zu%20verf%26uuml%3Bhren%2C%20habe%20sich%20Seianus%20von%20seiner%20eigenen%20Frau%20getrennt.%20Es%20kam%20sogar%20zu%20einer%20%26ouml%3Bffentlichen%20Rauferei%20zwischen%20dem%20geh%26ouml%3Brnten%20Ehemann%20und%20dem%20Liebhaber.%20Kurz%20darauf%2C%20am%2014.%20September%20des%20Jahres%2023%2C%20starb%20Drusus.%20Kein%20Wunder%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20ein%20-%20von%20Tacitus%20gen%26uuml%3B%26szlig%3Blich%20kolportiertes%20-%20Ger%26uuml%3Bcht%20behauptete%2C%20Seianus%20habe%20dessen%20Ehefrau%20dazu%20%26uuml%3Bberredet%2C%20ihn%20zu%20vergiften.%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3ETiberius%20schenkte%20diesen%20%26uuml%3Bblen%20Verleumdungen%20keinen%20Glauben%2C%20im%20Gegenteil%2C%20er%20baute%20systematisch%20Seianus%20zu%20seinem%20Nachfolger%20auf%2C%20bis%20er%20-%20aus%20uns%20heute%20nicht%20mehr%20nachvollziehbaren%20Gr%26uuml%3Bnden%20-%20von%20seiner%20Politik%20abwich%20und%20Seianus%20fallen%20lie%26szlig%3B.%20Die%20ehrw%26uuml%3Brdigen%20Senatoren%20r%26auml%3Bchten%20sich%3A%20Sie%20t%26ouml%3Bteten%20Seianus%20und%20rotteten%20seine%20ganze%20Familie%20aus.%20Als%20deshalb%20beim%20Tod%20des%20Tiberius%20kein%20Erbe%20vorhanden%20war%2C%20der%20%26uuml%3Bber%20die%20n%26ouml%3Btige%20Erfahrung%20verf%26uuml%3Bgte%2C%20%26uuml%3Bbergaben%20sie%20auf%20eigene%20Initiative%20dem%20jungen%20Caligula%20die%20herrscherlichen%20Privilegien.%20Der%20neue%20Kaiser%20versagte%20v%26ouml%3Bllig.%20Wohl%20kaum%20ein%20Senator%20wird%20sich%20eingestanden%20haben%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20Seianus%20seine%20Sache%20wohl%20besser%20gemacht%20h%26auml%3Btte.%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3ELiteratur%3A%3Cbr%20%2F%3EJ.%20Bleicken%2C%20Augustus.%20Berlin%201998.%3Cbr%20%2F%3EE.%20Meise%2C%20Der%20Sesterz%20des%20Drusus%20mit%20den%20Zwillingen%20und%20die%20Nachfolgepl%26auml%3Bne%20des%20Tiberius%2C%20JNG%2016%20(1966)%2C%207-22.%3Cbr%20%2F%3EZ.%20Yavetz%2C%20Tiberius.%20Der%20traurige%20Kaiser.%20M%26uuml%3Bnchen%201999.%3C%2Fp%3E";}}}}
```

Can someone tell me what this is? All articles are encoded like this and just want to use the text, html and images in there. Is there an existing php library to parse this gibberish? I already started to write a php script for parsing this but it's becoming an enormous endeavour since there are other articles that use different parameters etc....

Comment: It is a [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) string from PHP. Use `unserialize()` to check it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i'm on the right track :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) string, generated using PHP code. You will need to use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function in the PHP to work on it. Since, the first character in it is `a`; it is an array which has been serialized to string for portability.

Try (**[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/NTWOI50949)**):

```
  $s = 'a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:4:"TEXT";s:8:"elements";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:3:"RTE";s:7:"content";s:486:"%3Cp%3EDas%20r%26ouml%3Bmische%20Gemeinwesen%20war%20beim%20Tod%20des%20Augustus%20keine%20erbliche%20Monarchie.%20Die%20Herrschaft%20%26uuml%3Bber%20die%20R%26ouml%3Bmer%20ging%20nach%20seinem%20Tod%20nicht%20automatisch%20auf%20den%20n%26auml%3Bchsten%20m%26auml%3Bnnlichen%20Anverwandten%20%26uuml%3Bber.%20Im%20Gegenteil%2C%20komplizierte%2C%20rechtliche%20Schritte%20waren%20die%20Voraussetzung%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20der%20Thronwechsel%20problemlos%20von%20statten%20ging.%3C%2Fp%3E";}}}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGES";s:8:"elements";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGE1";s:7:"content";s:16:"570_a201ebec.jpg";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGE2";s:7:"content";s:0:"";}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:5:"CLASS";s:7:"content";s:12:"freigestellt";}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"LEGEND";s:7:"content";s:33:"Augustusstatue%20von%20Primaporta";}}}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:4:"TEXT";s:8:"elements";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:3:"RTE";s:7:"content";s:3544:"%3Cp%3EWas%20bedeutete%20das%20damals%20%26uuml%3Bberhaupt%2C%20Herrschaft%20%26uuml%3Bber%20die%20R%26ouml%3Bmer%3F%20Augustus%20behauptete%20ja%20von%20sich%20selbst%2C%20er%20habe%20lediglich%20an%20Autorit%26auml%3Bt%20die%20anderen%20R%26ouml%3Bmer%20%26uuml%3Bberragt.%20Doch%20die%20Wahrheit%20sah%20anders%20aus.%20Er%20verf%26uuml%3Bgte%20vor%20allem%20%26uuml%3Bber%20zwei%20Privilegien%2C%20die%20ihn%20zu%20einem%20unumschr%26auml%3Bnkten%20Herrscher%20machten.%20F%26uuml%3Br%20seine%20milit%26auml%3Brische%20Herrschaft%20war%20das%20%3Cem%3EImperium%20Proconsulare%3C%2Fem%3E%20am%20wichtigsten.%20W%26auml%3Bhrend%20ein%20einfacher%20senatorischer%20Prokonsul%20lediglich%20in%20einer%20Provinz%20sein%20Amt%20aus%26uuml%3Bbte%20und%20in%20dieser%20seiner%20Provinz%20tats%26auml%3Bchlich%20die%20gleichen%20Vollmachten%20besa%26szlig%3B%20wie%20Augustus%2C%20verf%26uuml%3Bgte%20der%20Kaiser%20%26uuml%3Bber%20eine%20ganze%20Reihe%20von%20Provinzen.%20Die%20waren%20zudem%20so%20ausgew%26auml%3Bhlt%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20alle%20wichtigen%20Heeresteile%20in%20ihnen%20stationiert%20waren.%20Damit%20war%20er%20nat%26uuml%3Brlich%20jedem%20anderen%20r%26ouml%3Bmischen%20Beamten%20milit%26auml%3Brisch%20weit%20%26uuml%3Bberlegen%20und%20konnte%20mit%20Waffengewalt%20jeden%20Widerstand%20brechen.%20Die%20Herrschaft%20des%20Augustus%20und%20seiner%20Nachfolger%20war%20-%20auch%20wenn%20sie%20es%20noch%20so%20gut%20zu%20verschleiern%20wu%26szlig%3Bten%20-%20nichts%20anderes%20als%20eine%20Milit%26auml%3Brdiktatur.%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3EUm%20die%20Senatoren%20aber%20in%20dem%20Glauben%20zu%20wiegen%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20alles%20seinen%20gewohnten%20demokratischen%20Gang%20ginge%2C%20lie%26szlig%3B%20sich%20Augustus%20eine%20zweite%20Macht%20verleihen%2C%20die%20Tribunicia%20Potestas.%20Sie%20r%26auml%3Bumte%20ihm%20die%20gleichen%20Privilegien%20ein%2C%20wie%20sie%20fr%26uuml%3Bher%20die%20Volkstribunen%20besessen%20hatten.%20So%20konnte%20der%20Kaiser%20ganz%20legal%20jeden%20Gesetzesvorschlag%20einbringen%20und%20gegen%20jeden%20Beschlu%26szlig%3B%20eines%20Beamten%20das%20Veto%20(%22ich%20verbiete%22)%20einlegen.%20Im%20wesentlichen%20st%26uuml%3Btzte%20sich%20das%20Kaisertum%20w%26auml%3Bhrend%20des%20gesamten%20ersten%20Jahrhunderts%20n.%20Chr.%20auf%20diese%20beiden%20Privilegien.%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3EDoch%20ein%20Sch%26ouml%3Bnheitsfehler%20blieb.%20Beide%20Vollmachten%20waren%20nicht%20erblich%2C%20sondern%20wurden%20vom%20Senat%20verliehen.%20Wollte%20nun%20Augustus%2C%20oder%20irgendein%20anderer%20Kaiser%20nach%20ihm%2C%20auf%20die%20Wahl%20seines%20Nachfolgers%20Einflu%26szlig%3B%20nehmen%2C%20so%20mu%26szlig%3Bte%20er%20durchsetzen%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20dieser%20Nachfolger%20noch%20zu%20seinen%20Lebzeiten%20das%20Imperium%20Proconsulare%20und%20die%20Tribunicia%20Potestas%20verliehen%20bekam.%20So%20gab%20es%20also%20-%20bei%20einer%20ordentlich%20geregelten%20Nachfolge%20-%20stets%20zwei%20%22Kaiser%22.%20Starb%20einer%20von%20ihnen%2C%20so%20lief%20alles%20weiter%20wie%20bisher%2C%20nur%20mu%26szlig%3Bte%20sich%20der%20%26Uuml%3Bberlebende%20wieder%20um%20einen%20neuen%20Mitregenten%20umsehen.%20Augustus%20hatte%20das%20mehrmals%20in%20seiner%20Amtszeit%20getan.%20Agrippa%20-%20Ehemann%20von%20Iulia%2C%20der%20Tochter%20des%20Augustus%2C%20und%20Vater%20der%20potentiellen%20Nachfolger%2C%20Caius%20und%20Lucius%20Caesar%20%26ndash%3B%20war%20sein%20Mitregent%20gewesen.%20Er%20wurde%20von%20Tiberius%20-%20dem%20Stiefsohn%20des%20Augustus%20-%20abgel%26ouml%3Bst.%3C%2Fp%3E";}}}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGES";s:8:"elements";a:4:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGE1";s:7:"content";s:16:"571_0633fda9.jpg";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"IMAGE2";s:7:"content";s:16:"572_05111ca7.jpg";}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:5:"CLASS";s:7:"content";s:12:"freigestellt";}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:6:"LEGEND";s:7:"content";s:335:"TIBERIUS%2C%2014-37%20AD.%20As%20im%20Namen%20des%20Drusus%20des%20J%C3%83%C2%BCngeren%2C%2022-23.%20PIETAS%20Verschleierte%20weibliche%20B%C3%83%C2%BCste%20mit%20Diadem%20n.%20r.%20Rv.%20DRVSVS%20CAESAR%20TI%20AVGVSTI%20F%20TR%20POT%20ITER%20um%20SC%2015%2C12%20g.%20BN%2048%2C%2074.%20BMC%20133%2C%2098.%20RIC%2097%2C%2043.%20C.%201.";}}}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:4:"TEXT";s:8:"elements";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"type";s:3:"RTE";s:7:"content";s:4164:"%3Cp%3EAuch%20Tiberius%20sorgte%20sich%20nach%20seiner%20Macht%26uuml%3Bbernahme%20um%20die%20Nachfolge.%20Er%20besa%26szlig%3B%20einen%20leiblichen%20Sohn%2C%20Drusus%2C%20und%20hatte%20auf%20Befehl%20des%20Augustus%20seinen%20Neffen%20Germanicus%20adoptiert.%20Damit%20verf%26uuml%3Bgte%20Tiberius%20%26uuml%3Bber%20zwei%20potentielle%20Mitherrscher.%20Wer%20nun%20die%20Macht%20mit%20ihm%20teilen%20sollte%2C%20dies%20lie%26szlig%3B%20Tiberius%20erst%20einmal%20offen.%20Er%20gab%20beiden%20jungen%20M%26auml%3Bnnern%20die%20Chance%2C%20sich%20in%20politischen%20und%20milit%26auml%3Brischen%20Aktionen%20zu%20bew%26auml%3Bhren.%20Erst%20als%20Germanicus%20im%20Jahre%2019%20n.%20Chr.%20starb%2C%20entschlo%26szlig%3B%20sich%20Tiberius%2C%20Drusus%20zum%20n%26auml%3Bchsten%20Kaiser%20zu%20machen%2C%20und%20veranla%26szlig%3Bte%20den%20Senat%2C%20seinem%20Sohn%20im%20Fr%26uuml%3Bhjahr%20des%20Jahres%2023%20die%20%3Cem%3ETribunicia%20Potestas%3C%2Fem%3E%20zu%20verleihen.%20Anl%26auml%3B%26szlig%3Blich%20dieses%20Ereignisses%20wurde%20unsere%20M%26uuml%3Bnze%20gepr%26auml%3Bgt.%20Wir%20lesen%20in%20der%20Umschrift%20DRVSVS%20CAESAR%20TI%20AVGVSTI%20F%20TR%20POT%20ITER%20Drusus%20Caesar%2C%20Sohn%20des%20Tiberius%20Augustus%2C%20der%20f%26uuml%3Br%20mehrere%20Jahre%20die%20Macht%20eines%20Tribunen%20inne%20hat.%20Damit%20h%26auml%3Btte%20nun%20eigentlich%20alles%20so%20sch%26ouml%3Bn%20geregelt%20ablaufen%20k%26ouml%3Bnnen.%20Doch%20Tacitus%20berichtet%20uns%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20Drusus%20einen%20Neider%20hatte%2C%20den%20Stadtpr%26auml%3Bfekten%20Seianus.%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3EWenn%20wir%20den%20packenden%20Bericht%20des%20Tacitus%20lesen%2C%20m%26uuml%3Bssen%20wir%20uns%20vor%20Augen%20halten%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20sein%20Autor%20stolz%20darauf%20war%2C%20im%20Senat%20zu%20sitzen%2C%20und%20auf%20einen%20Ritter%20wie%20Seianus%20nur%20ver%26auml%3Bchtlich%20herabblicken%20konnte.%20So%20unterstellte%20er%20Seianus%20alles%20Schlechte.%20Er%20behauptete%2C%20einzig%20sein%20Ehrgeiz%20sei%20der%20Grund%20gewesen%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20Seianus%20sich%20an%20die%20Ehefrau%20des%20Drusus%20heranmachte%2C%20die%20der%20leichtlebige%20Kaisersohn%20viel%20zu%20oft%20allein%20lie%26szlig%3B.%20Nur%20um%20Livilla%20zu%20verf%26uuml%3Bhren%2C%20habe%20sich%20Seianus%20von%20seiner%20eigenen%20Frau%20getrennt.%20Es%20kam%20sogar%20zu%20einer%20%26ouml%3Bffentlichen%20Rauferei%20zwischen%20dem%20geh%26ouml%3Brnten%20Ehemann%20und%20dem%20Liebhaber.%20Kurz%20darauf%2C%20am%2014.%20September%20des%20Jahres%2023%2C%20starb%20Drusus.%20Kein%20Wunder%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20ein%20-%20von%20Tacitus%20gen%26uuml%3B%26szlig%3Blich%20kolportiertes%20-%20Ger%26uuml%3Bcht%20behauptete%2C%20Seianus%20habe%20dessen%20Ehefrau%20dazu%20%26uuml%3Bberredet%2C%20ihn%20zu%20vergiften.%20%3Cbr%20%2F%3ETiberius%20schenkte%20diesen%20%26uuml%3Bblen%20Verleumdungen%20keinen%20Glauben%2C%20im%20Gegenteil%2C%20er%20baute%20systematisch%20Seianus%20zu%20seinem%20Nachfolger%20auf%2C%20bis%20er%20-%20aus%20uns%20heute%20nicht%20mehr%20nachvollziehbaren%20Gr%26uuml%3Bnden%20-%20von%20seiner%20Politik%20abwich%20und%20Seianus%20fallen%20lie%26szlig%3B.%20Die%20ehrw%26uuml%3Brdigen%20Senatoren%20r%26auml%3Bchten%20sich%3A%20Sie%20t%26ouml%3Bteten%20Seianus%20und%20rotteten%20seine%20ganze%20Familie%20aus.%20Als%20deshalb%20beim%20Tod%20des%20Tiberius%20kein%20Erbe%20vorhanden%20war%2C%20der%20%26uuml%3Bber%20die%20n%26ouml%3Btige%20Erfahrung%20verf%26uuml%3Bgte%2C%20%26uuml%3Bbergaben%20sie%20auf%20eigene%20Initiative%20dem%20jungen%20Caligula%20die%20herrscherlichen%20Privilegien.%20Der%20neue%20Kaiser%20versagte%20v%26ouml%3Bllig.%20Wohl%20kaum%20ein%20Senator%20wird%20sich%20eingestanden%20haben%2C%20da%26szlig%3B%20Seianus%20seine%20Sache%20wohl%20besser%20gemacht%20h%26auml%3Btte.%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3ELiteratur%3A%3Cbr%20%2F%3EJ.%20Bleicken%2C%20Augustus.%20Berlin%201998.%3Cbr%20%2F%3EE.%20Meise%2C%20Der%20Sesterz%20des%20Drusus%20mit%20den%20Zwillingen%20und%20die%20Nachfolgepl%26auml%3Bne%20des%20Tiberius%2C%20JNG%2016%20(1966)%2C%207-22.%3Cbr%20%2F%3EZ.%20Yavetz%2C%20Tiberius.%20Der%20traurige%20Kaiser.%20M%26uuml%3Bnchen%201999.%3C%2Fp%3E";}}}}';    
  $s_unserialized = unserialize($s);

  print_r($s_unserialized); // to check the unserialized array
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I was able to write a custom class for further processing. You have been a great help!